# mySQL regex selecting string and incremental number

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi so I have email addresses saved for example in below format:

```
NEWUSER1@domain.com
NEWUSER3@domain.com
NEWUSER2@domain.com
```

As can be seen everything is same in these email except for the number before `@` sign. I want to select the last biggest email address with that number in this case `NEWUSER3@domain.com` since `3` is biggest number in these emails.

I am not much aware about regex but I tried this:

```
SELECT id, email FROM tableName WHERE email regexp 'NEWUSER(\d+)@domain.com'
ORDER BY email DESC LIMIT 1
```

But it didn't work obviously **regex isn't correct** :( Can anyone help on how to select row with biggest number email out of these please ?

Comment: @zerkms: Yeah regex to parse emails in format `NEWUSER(\d+)@domain.com` where `\d` is a number you know but it doesn't return any rows obviously regex isn't correct

Comment: You want the last line ? i mean largest number will always at the last line ?

Comment: @Jageen: not necessaly it will always be last line, it could be anywhere but i want to get row with largest number in email. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM tableName where email like 'NEWUSER%' ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(email FROM 8) AS UNSIGNED) desc limit 1
```

Comment: well it works with warnings but still not ideal solution since it doesn't consider my explicit string `NEWUSER` and therefore may also return incorrect rows such as `ABCDEFG3@domain.com`

Comment: This only works when the email address pattern is always the same. It breaks when there are addresses like NEWGROUP1@domain.com

Comment: You want sort numerals only?  hjfhgkhdf45@jfdhgj.com

Comment: @jey: I only want to get rows with `NEWUSER` term in email field

Comment: @Dev01:SELECT * FROM tables where website like 'NEWUSER%' ORDER BY
CAST(SUBSTR(website FROM 8) AS UNSIGNED) desc